# Proper capitalization for titles in Python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a library that properly capitalizes a given string by assuming it is a title. I know there is string.title(), but it capitalizes every work, not just the one's that should be capitalized. Anyone know any libraries?

Examples of words that should not be capitalized in titles:

- Propositions (in, from, etc.)
- Articles (a, an, the)
- van
- de

Comment: How should "driving a van home" be capitalized?

Comment: "Driving a Van Home"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The term to Google for is "titlecase". The [first hit](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2008/05/27/titlecasepy-titlecase-in-python/) is [the `titlecase` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/titlecase/0.5.1):

```
$ pip install titlecase
...
$ python
...
>>> from titlecase import titlecase
>>> titlecase('the spam and eggs')
'The Spam and Eggs'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capitolise a string but only capitolise certain words, you'll need to specify in some list what words you do not want capitolised and then do something similar to:

```
excluded_words = ["words","you","want","excluded"]

titled = [word.capitalize() if word not in excluded_words else word 
           for word in title.split(" ")]
```

This is only if you have some weird (or non implemented) standard you wish to use.
If you can find a package that does this and complies with the standards you want, then use that instead.

Comment: use a set instead: `excluded_words = {"words","you","want","excluded"}`. Sets use hashes, which are very efficient.